What are the available sbt new templates?
The Getting Started guide for Scala says:

Run the command sbt new scala/scala3.g8 to create a Scala 3 project, or sbt new scala/hello-world.g8 to create a Scala 2 project.

Are there any more sbt new templates available? Where do I find that list?

You can see at sbt docs, the section sbt new and Templates

Giter8 support
Giter8 is a templating project originally started by Nathan Hamblen in 2010, and now maintained by the foundweekends project.
For more, see Giter8 templates on the Giter8 wiki.

There is a list with templates for different types of projects and libraries.
